# programmatically navigate using react router problem

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with ReactJS. I have a JSON file like this:

```
const products = [
{
    '_id':'1',
    'name':'Airpod',
    'image':'/images/airpod.png',
    'describtion':
       'this producted by Apple Company. made in USA',

    'brand': 'Apple',
    'catagory': 'Electronics',
    'price': 89.99,
    'contInStock': 10,
    'rating': 4.5,
    'numReviews':12,   
}
```

in app.js :

```js
<Route path='/product/:id' component={ProductScreen} />
```

ProductScreen:

```
function ProductScreen( { match } ) {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id == match.params.id)
    
    return(
         <div>
             {product.name}
         </div>
    )
}


export default ProductScreen
```

It gives the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: What do you get when you log product to the console after the find function ;)

Comment: its give the 'undefined' error in console --> console.log(product)

Comment: @EtAnne Then maybe the find function isn't successful. What do you get when you log `match` to the console?

Comment: So, the answer is passing the prop of product to the ProductScreen within the route component in app.js ;)
Also not sure why you are destructuring match in your ProductScreen file, there is no match attribute on the project object

Comment: object log currectly when i log match

Comment: Maybe change `match.params.id` to only `match.id`. These are all off the top of my head since I really don't know what the `match` object looks like.

Answer (score 0):

here `match` is undefined.
For dynamic routes, we can read the dynamic paths from `params`. For that a hook `useParams()` should be imported from `'react-router-dom'`. This hook will return a `params` object as shown below. This params object will have key-value pairs where keys are dynamic segments leading to the required page.

```
const ProductScreen = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === params.id)
    return (
        <h1>{product.name}</h1>
    )
}
export default ProductScreen;
```